# Pdf to Pdf redirect rules not working in web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config, iis-8.5, umbraco8

I have tried to redirect the pdf to pdf by the following the rule in web.config

```
<rule name="r_1" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^/media/peedin5t/xxx.pdf$" ignoreCase="false" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="/media/beebz4yx/xxx1.pdf" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Even I have cleared the cache still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

This rule works fine on my side, please modify ^/media/peedin5t/xxx.pdf$ to ^media/peedin5t/xxx.pdf$.

```
<rule name="r_1" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^media/peedin5t/xxx.pdf$" ignoreCase="false" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="/media/beebz4yx/xxx1.pdf" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I have checked the maximum age(Max-age) of Response Header from the browser. The cloudflare cache is set to the maximum age of 2592000(720 hours). That's why it is not reflecting the changes. So we asked the cloudflare team to clear the cache the issue has solved

[image]